# How to create a .wsdl file in .Net2.0 for a web service?

Tags: c#-2.0

I am making a window service in .Net2.0 on which I am adding a web reference of a web service in .Net2.0 only, present at the Linux server. For that I am requiring a .wsdl file that is to be generated after i compile the Web service OR I have to make it manually on my own.

I am not able to generate the .wsdl neither automatically nor manually (don't know how to make it).

Kinldy provide me with a solution if someone is aware of the working of .Net Web Services at different Servers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is url of your service: http://localhost/SuperWebService , if you click this url: http://localhost/SuperWebService?wsdl it will generate WSDL

Comment: Thanks dear Andrey. I got the .wsdl created on my own by adding the web service reference to my project and then finding it under the web reference folder of the project folder in which i added the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a proxy for calling a web service. The simplest way to do this is using the `Add Web Reference` option when you right click on your project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks dear Ajay. I got the .wsdl created on my own by adding the web service reference to my project and then finding it under the web reference folder of the project folder in which i added the reference.